# Do a class's methods have to be the same for serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

I feel pretty stupid asking this, but for serialization over sockets via ObjectInput/Output Streams to work, do the classes in the program receiving it have to be the exact same and will produce an error if the classes aren't the exact same, or can they have a few different methods/etc? If this is too simple a question to ask here I'm sorry.

Comment: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#5251) Specifically under 1.7 Accessing Serializable Fields of a Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the java compiler will generate a `private static long serialVersionUID` and this ID must match at each end. If the methods are not the same the generated id won't match.

The simple way around this is to hard code the id.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1;
```

and it will always match.

The next step is that the fields should match also.  However, these can be changed if you write your own `readObject()` method and in some classes do this because the field shave changed over time.

[Spec for how serialVersionUID is calculated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100)

The sequence of items in the stream is as follows:

1. The class name.
2. The class modifiers written as a 32-bit integer.
3. The name of each interface sorted by name.
4. For each field of the class sorted by field name (except private static and private transient fields: 
   a. The name of the field.
   b. The modifiers of the field written as a 32-bit integer.
   c. The descriptor of the field.
5. If a class initializer exists, write out the following:
   a. The name of the method, .
   b. The modifier of the method, java.lang.reflect.Modifier.STATIC, written as a 32-bit integer.
   c. The descriptor of the method, ()V.
6. For each non-private constructor sorted by method name and signature:
   a. The name of the method, < init >.
   b. The modifiers of the method written as a 32-bit integer.
   c. The descriptor of the method.
7. For each non-private method sorted by method name and signature:
   a. The name of the method.
   b. The modifiers of the method written as a 32-bit integer.
   c. The descriptor of the method.
8. The SHA-1 algorithm is executed on the stream of bytes produced by DataOutputStream and produces five 32-bit values sha[0..4].
9. The hash value is assembled from the first and second 32-bit values of the SHA-1 message digest. If the result of the message digest, the five 32-bit words H0 H1 H2 H3 H4, is in an array of five int values named sha, the hash value would be computed as follows:

Comment: Are you sure the methods come into play when generating the `serialVersionUID`? Could you site the spec?

Comment: @arshajii I am not saying it should use the methods, but it does. even the constructors and the static initializer block. !?

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder why methods/constructors must be taken into account. In any case, +1.

Comment: @arshajii Or interfaces for that matter. Or change an argument or return type of a package local or protected method.

Comment: @arshajii BTW when you have nested classes, it generates methods for accessing private members.  I wonder if accessing a field or not in a nested class changes its sVUID.

Comment: He is correct, the methods are taken into account with the serial version generation, annoyingly enough.

Comment: I tried setting the serial version as per the above answer, but I'm getting this error even though both have the private static long serialVersionUID = -1;

java.io.InvalidClassException: [class]; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7905184098218796111, local class serialVersionUID = 3625557838997243765

Comment: @VoidWhisperer Sorry, it must be `private static final long` or it will ignore it. To read a class which you have already written, you need to use the value it recorded i.e. `private static final long serialVersionUID = -7905184098218796111L;`

Comment: By default the *JVM* will generate a default serialVersionUID.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using default (de)serialization there are several compatible changes that can be made without breaking it, see [Versioning of Serializable Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) which in **5.6.1 Incompatible Changes** lists the following as incompatible changes. Specifically, adding methods does not break serialization.

That said, the default serialization is known to be appropriate in very limited use-cases, and it would better of using other methods, such as `JSON`.

- Deleting fields - If a field is deleted in a class, the stream written will not contain its value. When the stream is read by an earlier class, the value of the field will be set to the default value because no value is available in the stream. However, this default value may adversely impair the ability of the earlier version to fulfill its contract.
- Moving classes up or down the hierarchy - This cannot be allowed since the data in the stream appears in the wrong sequence.
- Changing a nonstatic field to static or a nontransient field to transient - When relying on default serialization, this change is equivalent to deleting a field from the class. This version of the class will not write that data to the stream, so it will not be available to be read by earlier versions of the class. As when deleting a field, the field of the earlier version will be initialized to the default value, which can cause the class to fail in unexpected ways.
- Changing the declared type of a primitive field - Each version of the class writes the data with its declared type. Earlier versions of the class attempting to read the field will fail because the type of the data in the stream does not match the type of the field.
- Changing the writeObject or readObject method so that it no longer writes or reads the default field data or changing it so that it attempts to write it or read it when the previous version did not. The default field data must consistently either appear or not appear in the stream.
- Changing a class from Serializable to Externalizable or vice versa is an incompatible change since the stream will contain data that is incompatible with the implementation of the available class.
- Changing a class from a non-enum type to an enum type or vice versa since the stream will contain data that is incompatible with the implementation of the available class.
- Removing either Serializable or Externalizable is an incompatible change since when written it will no longer supply the fields needed by older versions of the class.
- Adding the writeReplace or readResolve method to a class is incompatible if the behavior would produce an object that is incompatible with any older version of the class.

Comment: You should attribute this extensive quotation from the Specification correctly.

Comment: @EJP not sure how the attribution is incorrect. Can you please elaborate?